# Difference between Role Assignments and appRoleAssignments in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, azure-service-principal, azure-identity

What is the difference between Role Assignments and appRoleAssignments in Microsoft Azure?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary difference is that `Role Assignments` is an Azure Subscription thing while `App Role Assignments` is Microsoft Graph API thing.

You use `Role Assignments` to assign access to users in your Azure AD to various resources in an Azure Subscription. Based on the role assigned, a user is able to perform activities against the Azure resources in an Azure Subscription.

`App Role Assignments` is essentially assigning access to users in your Azure AD to the custom roles that you created for your Azure AD application. These roles are essentially custom roles specific to your application (e.g. Administrator, User etc.) and is used in your application code to restrict access to various parts of your application e.g. a user in "Administrator" app role can access admin screens while a user in "User" app role can't.